# What is method for getting time and date which less to current date and time

Tags: php

I am new to PHP.
I want to deduct a 2 hour time slot from current date and time to get date and time as output of above query. How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: _"as output of above query"_ What query? - Also, what have you tried?

Comment: A dead simple `time() - 60 * 60 * 2` would do... Please investigate *a little* into the topic at hand before asking random strangers on the internet.

Comment: deceze its basically a time-zone setting problem which i didn't explained clearly, but now resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the built in function strtotime is ideal.

```
<?php
    echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s',strtotime('-2 hours'));
?>
```

Comment: As an extra, you can always look these kind of things up on php.net

Comment: $daySTART = date("d-y-m h : i : s",strtotime("-2 hours")) ;//'2015-07-14 08:00:00';

$dayEND= date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "$daySTART";
echo "$dayEND";

output:

31-15-07 03 : 25 : 21

which is ~45 min ahead to current time